# Why a Windows console with Chinese code page set can show a UTF-16 encoded character?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, locale

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx):

> "For the Microsoft C/C++ compiler, the source and execution character sets are both ASCII."

C++03

2.1 Phases of translation

> "..***Any source file character not in the basic source character set***
>   (2.2) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that
>   character. (***An implementation may use any internal encoding***, so long
>   as an actual extended character encountered in the source file, and
>   the same extended character expressed in the source file as a
>   universal-character-name (i.e. using the \uXXXX notation), are handled
>   equivalently.)"

2.13.2 Character literals

> "A universal-character-name is translated to the encoding, in the
>   execution character set, of the character named. If there is no such
>   encoding, the universal-character-name is translated to an
>   implementation-defined encoding."

To test which execution character set is used by MSVC++, I wrote the following code:

```
wchar_t *str = L"中";
unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(str);
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(L"中"); ++i)
{
   printf ("%x ", *(p + i));
}
```

The output shows that `2d 4e 0 0`, and `0x4e2d` is the [UTF-16 encoding](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4E2D/index.htm) of this Chinese character. So I conclude: *UTF-16 is used as execution character set by MSVC* (My version: 2012 4.5.50709)

After, I tried to print this character out to a Windows console. Since the default locale used by console is `"C"`, I set the locale to code page 936 representing simplified Chinese characters.

```
// use the execution environment locale setting, which is 936
wchar_t *str = L"中";
char* locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
wprintf (L"%ls\n", str);
```

Which outputs:

```
中
```

What I'm curious about is, how can a character encoded in UTF-16 be decoded by a Windows console whose locale(decoder) is set to non-UTF-16(MS code page 936)? How can that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it.

In Microsoft C++ 2008(probably 2005+), CRT functions as `wprintf`, `wcout` are implemented such that they convert a wide string literal as `L"中"` encoded in UTF-16, under the hood, to match the current locale/code page setting. So what happens here is that `L"中"` is converted to bytes `D6 D0` in code page 936 for simplified Chinese.

I was wrong that `setlocale` set the console code page. It just set the current program code page which is used by CRT functions during the "conversion". For changing console code page, command `chcp` or Win API `SetConsoleOputputCP()` achieves.

Since my console's default page is 936, that character can be correctly shown w/o problem.

Comment: You may use the debugger and take a look at the memory location to be **sure** of what's happening underneath.

Answer (score 1):

> how can a character encoded in UTF-16 be decoded by a Windows console whose locale(decoder) is set to non-UTF-16

There are two ways you can write text to the console. The byte way, using the Win32 API `WriteConsoleA`, gives you characters from bytes interpreted using the console's code page ("ANSI"). The Unicode way, `WriteConsoleW`, receives a UTF-16LE string and writes the characters to the console directly without having to worry about what code page it is using.

The stdio function `printf` uses `WriteConsoleA` when the output is an interactive console. The `wprintf` function, from VS 2005 on at least, calls `WriteConsoleW`.

Comment: If console uses the default locale which is `"C"`, or use a different one e.g., `"English"`, `wprintf` won't output the correct character `"中"`. So I'm afraid it's not the case.